# ¿Porque cuando quiero guardar un string no lo hace?

Tags: c, archivo, binary-files

```
printf("Ingresa el nombre de la calle);
gets(dat.nombre);
```

Ya teniendo previamente el struct

```
typedef struct{char nombre[45]};dat
```

al ejecutar el programa no me deja nisiquera ingresar alguna letra, alguno podria decirme mi error?

Comment: Lo más probable es que justo antes de ese `gets()` hayas hecho un `scanf()` de un número. Ese `scanf()` habrá dejado en el buffer del teclado, sin leer, el retorno de carro introducido por el usuario. Cuando llegas al `gets()` ese retorno de carro es lo primero que se encuentra y ya que `gets()` lee hasta el primer retorno de carro, pues devuelve inmediatamente una línea vacía. Si es este el caso, debes "consumir" el retorno de carro supérfluo antes de llamar a `gets()`, por ejemplo con `getchar()`

Comment: Lo mas probable es que sea lo que dice @abulafia, pero no puedo asegurar nada. Si eso no te funciona, procura venir con un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Asi sera mas facil que te ayudemos

Answer (score 0):

Bueno veo unos problemas en tu código, imagino que solo es error de tipeo al momento de redactar tu inconveniente pero igualmente...

1. `printf("Ingresa el nombre de la calle);` le falta el final de `char[]` -> `"`
2. `typedef struct{char nombre[45]};dat` que yo sepa esto se declara de la siguiente forma `typedef struct{char nombre[45];} NombreStructAnonima; NombreStructAnonima dat;`
3. NO debes utilizar `gets()` no es seguro por el buffer restante, lo mejor es usar `fgets()`

Solventando esos dos inconvenientes el código quedaría:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    typedef struct{char nombre[45];} NombreStructuraAnonima;
    NombreStructuraAnonima dat;
    printf("Ingresa el nombre de la calle:\n");
    fgets(dat.nombre, 45 , stdin); // seguro ya que indica que solo vas a leer 45 characteres sin tomar el salto de linea de tipo input.
    // gets(dat.nombre); // inseguro por el buffer restante, pero igualmente funciona.
    printf("Dato ingresado\n");
    puts(dat.nombre); // mostramos lo que digitamos.
    return 0;
}
```

acá te dejo un link donde puedes ver el código funcionando adecuadamente:
[Ejemplo de código](https://onlinegdb.com/SJCywTVjw)

Sí tu problema es mayor, puedes proporcionar más código de lo que intentas realizar.